# Show/hide form depending on hyperlink clicked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink, visible

I have made 3 different forms and each form contains a div with the same classname as in the other forms. (so they overlap)

I also made a link section with three links to choose which div/form should be shown but i cant get it to work.

I have tried many things but the closest i came was clicking a link and having the div shown for less than a seconds. Please help.

I made a new code, same concept but the original code was probably too long to post here.

```
<body>
<div class="links">
<table>
<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showdiv('first','second','third')" >first</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showdiv('second','first','third')" >second</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showdiv('third','second','first')" >Third</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<form name="first">
<div id="first" class="content">
-------------
</div>
</form>
<form name"second">
<div id="second" class="content">
//////////////
</div>
</form>
<form name="third">
<div id=third class="content">
++++++++++++++
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function hide_all(){
    document.getElementById("first").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("third").style.display = 'none';
}
hide_all()
    function showdiv(a,b,c) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById(b).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(c).style.display = 'none';      
}
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As you can probably see im new to html and javascript :)

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: Please share the code for easy understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.visibility="hidden"
```

Comment: At first I did yes but then I used
document.getElementById("id").style.display="none"/"block"

but then i couldnt get it visible again.

Comment: to get it visible again just use visibility="visible"

Answer (score 0):

`#link` is ID of the clicked link and each link has class name called `.links` once you link the link, the clicked link will be hidden and other links will be shown

```
$('#link').click(function(){
   $('.links').css('visibility', 'visible');
   $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
})
```

As I cant see your code assume this may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("id").style.visibility="show"
```

also work to visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing all three ids pass only id of element to show and before showing element hide all elements by class:

```
function showdiv(idToHide) {
   var array = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
     array[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   document.getElementById(idToHide).style.display='';
}
```

and call it:

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showdiv('first')" >first</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showdiv('second')" >second</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showdiv('third')" >Third</a></td></tr>
</table>
```